# Pandas fund valuation

Tags: pandas

I have the returns for the stockmarket, and dividend rate as raw data. These are in a data frame and one row per year I have a set of contributions to make into the market, also in the data frame

For a given year, the

```
end_fund_valuation = previous_years_closing_fund_valuation * (1 + return + dividend rate) + contribution
```

Is there a way of calculating this in one hit? [Shift function?]

Or if it has to be row by row, what's the best way of doing that?

Comment: could you put a sample of the data so that we could look at this?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is what we are after